# can we prove that a certain supremum of affine functions is frechet differentiable or at least continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space. Let $A\colon \operatorname{dom} A\to X$ be linear operator with closed graph (not necessarily bounded). Define
$$
g\colon \operatorname{dom}A\to \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto \sup_{y\in \operatorname{dom}A}\{<Ax,y>-<Ay,y>\}.
$$
If $\forall x\in \operatorname{dom}A$ we have $g(x)<+\infty$. Can we prove that 
$g$ is Fréchet-differentiable (or at least continuous) on $\operatorname{dom}A$.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, please say so, and let us know what you tried. (The fact that it has been posted twice suggests this.)

Comment: No it is not. I did not get any replies for the first one and I thought the title was irrelevant so I changed it. I know the question is a mix between operator theory and convex analysis and I do not know what is the best tag/title?

Comment: Well, to be fair, it may not have received attention because nobody knows how to answer it :-) I'm not certain myself. Also, do know that instead of re-posting, you should just *edit* your post. Both the title and content can be edited. Indeed, this is *encouraged* if doing so improves the question.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Appreciate your reply.